# Compute means between time steps for given duration values in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

For example, I have 5 time steps and a duration value:

```
TimeSteps = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16];
Duration = [5, 3, 3];
```

I want to automatically generate the means between the time steps for every duration. In this case, the result would look like this:

```
Result = [mean([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), mean([10, 11, 12]), mean([14, 15, 16])];
```

This will lead to:

```
Result = [6, 11, 15];
```

I have a 474x1 duration vector, so I need to automatize this. If anyone can help, it would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to apply the `mean` function to a partition of your `TimeSteps` that has the sizes in `Duration`:

```
Partition = mat2cell(TimeSteps, 1, Duration);
Result    = cellfun(@mean, Partition)
```

If you're a fan of one-liners:

```
Result = cellfun(@mean, mat2cell(TimeSteps, 1, Duration));
```

*Note:* Please take in account that this solution is posted for row vectors; change the `mat2cell` call for column vectors.

Comment: This is even better than the `accumarray`-one!

Answer (score 4):

It can be done easily with [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). This works for row or column vectors.

```
ind = [];
ind(cumsum(Duration(end:-1:1))) = 1;
ind = cumsum(ind(end:-1:1)); %// generate grouping index for accumarray
Result = (accumarray(ind(:), TimeSteps(:))./Duration(:)).';
```

Comment: Off-topic, but: have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28497857/2586922)? Can you make any sense out of it?

Comment: Hmm Let me see, I did have a cursory glance at that discussion, need to look into it in detail.

Comment: Read the first lines of the question, got into `accumarray`-mode, scrolled down, my adrenaline levels are normal again.

Comment: @knedlsepp What! Are you _ever_ out of `acumarray`-mode?

Comment: I guess that's the reason I was too late. ;-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Well that other question doesn't make sense to me either. I think OP must have posted some sort of minimal code that could reproduce that error.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. The answer doesn't make any sense to me either (that imaginary part stuff). And it got accepted. Strange

Comment: Strangest thing in my one year experience on SO haha! :)

Answer (score 3):

Using **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)**'s masking capability -

```
%// Setup mask to be used to map Timesteps values onto a 2D matrix
mask = bsxfun(@ge,Duration(:).',[1:max(Duration)]') %//'

%// Initiliaze the 2D matrix where Timesteps values would be put with NaNs
vals = nan(size(mask))
%// Now, put those values
vals(mask) = TimeSteps

%// Find mean along columns for the final output
Result = nanmean(vals,1)
```

Output -

```
Result =
     6    11    15
```

Comment: Good approach, but may be memory-hungry

Comment: @LuisMendo Of course would depend on the Durations, I mean for performance.